# How to create a inflow outflow table where we need to use 2 different date fields

Tags: excel, quickbase

I am looking for Records either opened or closed current month. in Excel or quickbase, it is only allowing me to use 1 date field for the red, but i need to use both start and end date for the data flow.
raw data on the left and looking to create the right. if i can figure out the table, i can then make inflow outflow graph

1. Filter for either created current month or has end date of current month [done]
2. not sure how to pivot for 1 date column when i need to pull from 2 date fields. help needed here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Quickbase you can evaluate multiple fields in a filter like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(C2="closed",D2,A2)
```